# Corona SDK composer and overlays

Tags: lua, overlay, coronasdk, composer-php

I'm simply trying to use the `composer.showOverlay()` to display game-over, pause menu's etc.

I'm using the `composer.showOverlay("gameoverlay",options)` to call the overlay when a scene ends(Timer goes to zero etc), but I'm getting an error telling me I'm trying to call a wrong module, like my pause.lua isn't properbly formatted 
It looks like this

```
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()
local myData = require( "myData" )

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- All code outside of the listener functions will only be executed ONCE unless "composer.removeScene()" is called.
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- local forward references should go here

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-- "scene:create()"unction scene:hide( event )
function scene:hide( event )
   local sceneGroup = self.view
   local phase = event.phase
   local parent = event.parent  --reference to the parent scene object

   if ( phase == "will" ) then
      -- Call the "resumeGame()" function in the parent scene

   end
end

-- By some method (a "resume" button, for example), hide the overlay
-- composer.hideOverlay( "fade", 400 )

scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
return scene

    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Initialize the scene here.
    -- Example: add display objects to "sceneGroup", add touch listeners, etc

    local background = display.newRect( 0, 0, display.actualContentHeigh, display.actualContentWidth
    bacground:setFillColor( black ) )







-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Listener set)

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

This is far from the only version of the gameoverlay.lua I have used. I also tried using the normal setup for composer scenes. 
scene:create
scene:show
scene:hide
scene:destroy.

Still got the same error which looks like

```
Attempting to load scene from invalid scene module (gameoverlay.lua). Did you forget to return the scene object at the end of the scene module? (e.g. 'return scene')
Attempting to load scene from invalid scene module (gameoverlay.lua). Did you forget to return the scene object at the end of the scene module? (e.g. 'return scene')
```

Comment: There is likely a traceback message before the "Attempting to load scene" message because as pointed out by @user2276554 the problem is that your module fails to load but the reason why is in error prior to the one you show. There are so many possibilities like `myData.Lua` not found etc. Your questions on SO lack critical info and show insufficient debugging effort, but unfortunately SO is not a debugging support forum it is a q&a forum.  Its OK to not know what error data is telling but you do have to learn outside of SO how to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Well i see your point. 
But I don't understand why any other file could cause a problem. I have a functioning game, where the game can end or i can pause it and end it, go to home screen, go to level select and start a level again, without a problem.
My issue is only when I'm using the composer.showOverlay().

I will try some deeper debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file gameoverlay.lua that I was trying to run through the composer.showOverlay() was an empty file, and the gameoverlay.lua that I was working on was placed in a wrong directory *Major facepalm*.

If run with the composer.gotoScene() I would get a error saying that the "sceneName" was a nil value(because it was empty).

**Solution**
Make sure that the file is not empty, and is requiring composer and has a proper composer scene setup.

Answer (score 0):

You have two returns in your code, so the portion that creates the sceneGroup will not be run. Secondly, I think that Lua throws an error and this module does not get loaded, so the scene is never returned and hence your error.

Comment: I changed the gameOverlay to the template found here;http://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/01/21/introducing-the-composer-api-plus-tutorial/ Still not working :/